# Can RabbitMQ be used for one to one conversations?

Tags: rabbitmq

I would like to make some sort of email or sms server.

You send a message to `RabbitMQ` with tag "pseudo", and the user "pseudo" listens to messages with tag "pseudo".

However in the tutorials `RabbitMQ` doesn't mention that. There are topics, routing keys, ...
This looks similar but it seems to me that there has to be 1 queue per "topic"/"tag"/...
I wonder if you can have a very high number of queues or not, or if RabbitMQ is just inappropriate for this usage. Thanks

Comment: Why would you need different queues for these? You can have different users subscribe different topics and then you can publish to these specific topics to send messages to specific people. IMHO, you can have just one MQ to establish this system.

Comment: @Alpay So 1 queue for ALL messages, and what I call "tag" is a topic ? i.e clients would do queue.consume(topic=my_username, callback...) ? From the doc it looks like topics are different than queues

Comment: Topics are some kind of identifiers of messages. Suppose you have 2 clients, `clientA` and `clientB`, who subscribed to topics with same names. When you want to put a message that should be consumed by `clientA`, you need to put it with topic `clientA`. Notice that, topics can have hierarchical structures and accept wildcards, so that you are able to send a message to more than one clients if you design your topics appropriately.

Comment: @Alpay I don't see in thedoc (`basic_consume`) any argument for the tag/topic to watch. How do you watch a queue and say you want to listen only to `clientA` ? http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/channel.html

Comment: @Alpay in the RabbitMQ tutorial, a new temporary queue is created, and it is bounded to the exchange with the topic filter. This works fine but messages sent to the queue before the receiver wakes up are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

The base implementation is easy.

You can create a topic `Exchange` for example called `“conversations”` than you can bind to it a persistent queue for each user, with a routing-key.

The queues number is not a problem because your system have to scale and RabbitMQ can scale without problem.

Anyway I think the problem is not a queues number, but there are other most suitable technologies for implements your system.

XMPP is one of them, I tried ejabbed but there are other servers.

WhatsApps for examples uses a custom XMPP.

Another problem is how to integrate the mobile application, with XMPP you can find some ready libraries as https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework